# Rendering components in different containers while sharing state

Tags: reactjs

I have an HTML page pre-rendered by WordPress and three React components: `<App />`, `<Component />` and `<AnotherComponent />`.

There are two ID div containers inside the HTML page (`div` `id="component"` and `div` `id="anotherComponent"`) that are separated and I want to render React components on. Also they share some state. I want to use `<App />` to write all the logic and event handling and then pass state (`this.props.counter`) to each component.

[image]

I would like to use `ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('component'));` for each component and use the `<App />` to control the logic but how would I pass state to each component, and what would I `render()` in the `<App />`.

What is the best way to go with this one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ReactDOM.render` is like the main method of a React application. All the react related concepts like components, state, and context starts from here. You can call `ReactDOM.render` multiple times on the same page with the same container DOM node or different container DOM nodes. If the container is the same, this will perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to reflect the latest React element. But if container nodes are different, it will create two different React roots and those are totally independent of each other. There is no shared state or context between these two React roots and it's pretty much like running two different React applications on the same page.

Also, after rendering root element with `ReactDOM.render` into a container node, all other descendant elements will be rendered inside it by React and we don't have any control to change where they get rendered (this will change in the future).

So in your case, if you want to render these two components in different container nodes, you won't be able to have an App component which keeps a shared state or event handling. But instead of that you can create two different React roots and share objects and methods between them via props.

```
const data = {/*...*/}

ReactDOM.render(<Component data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('component'));

ReactDOM.render(<AnotherComponent data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('anotherComponent'));
```

However, if you want to change these props at some point you will have to rerender the root component manually. As an example, if you have a `counter` variable which updates in every second you have to rerender your roots with each new value.

```
let couter = 0

setInterval(function(){
  counter++

  ReactDOM.render(<Component data={data} />,
    document.getElementById('component'));

  ReactDOM.render(<AnotherComponent data={data} />,
    document.getElementById('anotherComponent'));

}, 1000)
```

Another good alternative will be using a Redux like state management library. You can have a single `store` and share it between two roots. I highly recommend this approach if you need to share a very complex state between two roots.

```
const store = createStore(/* ... */)

// ...

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Component />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('component')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AnotherComponent />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('anotherComponent')
);
```

When you use Redux, you will connect your `Component` and `AnotherComponent` to the `store` with [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) higher-order component. Under the hood, this will [subscribe](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe) your component to `store` changes and rerender the component when the state is changed using component's [`forceUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) method. So you don't have to manually call the `ReactDOM.render` method as long as you change the state by dispatching actions to the store.

Comment: That's a fantastic detailed answer and I'm fully enlightened. Thank you very much :) PS: Just a question, would Redux run the ReactDOM.render method automatically when state is updated?

Comment: @pmqa I'm glad it helped you. I updated the answer with some more details on how Redux approach works.

Comment: Fantastic. The Redux approach looks like it is the way. Thanks again, Tharaka.

Comment: I thought maybe I was the only one on the interwebs doing this, but so glad to find your answer, thanks!  In my case, I have an absolute positioned overlay component that I want to display when a user clicks a thumbnail, but the two components are separated by other elements within the html file, like in this question.  One thing I'm not sure of is if it's acceptable to call ReactDOM.render(ComponentA) inside a click handler of Component A, to hide component A (close button) (I pass visible={false} as a prop.  But the only alternative is to update state from props...seems bad.