# React.createElement and receiving the props' changes

Tags: reactjs

I need to reflect the changes that are made for props to the component instances that are generated by `React.createElement`. (Props are changed where they belong to, *not* in the child).

Apparently if I generate a class in JSX, `componentWillReceiveProps` fires:

```
<ContainerContents window_width={this.state.window_width} window_height={this.state.window_height} />
```

But `componentWillReceiveProps` does not fire if generate exact same component class instance with `React.createElement`:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(ContainerContents, {window_width: this.state.window_width, window_height: this.state.window_height}), 
        document.getElementById("someDOMElementID"));
```

Is it a normal behavior? And is there a way to handle this objective?

Comment: In the first example which is JSX, you are putting `<ContainerContents .../>` within a `ReactDOM.render()` call is it? Can you make a small fiddle recreating the same?

Comment: @AftabKhan, nope, the first one is directly in the render function. I believe the issue is as stated by Tharaka Wijebandara.

Comment: That was exactly why I asked that. Inside a react class you can write JSX or `React.createElement` it will have all the lifecycle hooks. But you will lose it if you put stuff directly into `ReactDOM.render`

Comment: Yes @AftabKhan, that was my case. I changed the width/height logic (lucky me for this time!) and moved it into the child component. So no more props, I am dealing with only the states.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using `ReactDOM.render` method. It will create a new React component root which is totally isolated from your original component root. So you can't expect the normal behavior with it.

If you want to render `ContainerContents` into a specific div, it's bit hard right now in React. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373375/rendering-components-in-different-containers-while-sharing-state) might help you with that. But it's not what you need just removing `ReactDOM.render` and keeping only the `React.createElement` will work. Actually, that's what you get when JSX get transform to the JavaScript in the compile process.